# Javascript Key Pressed + setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am making a game with html and javascript. Just for clarification, this is not a duplicate or anything. Nothing has the answer I need. Also before I explain, I want to say I have no trouble with the key listener, my game knows when a key is pressed and when it is released. Okay, I have 5 frames of a character walking. I have a while loop that basically says while the key D is pressed or Right arrow is pressed, then increment the frames to make it look like the character is walking. Then it has a setTimeout function that pauses for 1/10 of a second. This should make it look like the character is walking. I know it has something to do with the setTimeout() function. Here is the while loop:

```
while (keys[68] || keys[39]) {
    charFrame++;
    setTimeout(function() {

    }, 100);
}
```

Then here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Sparring Spartans</title>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var width = canvas.width;
        var height = canvas.height;
        var groundX = 0, groundY = 400;
        var playerx = width/2, playery = groundY-120;
        var charFrame = 1;
        var speed = 4;
        var keys = [];
        window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
            keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        }, false);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
            delete keys[e.keyCode];
        }, false);

        var spartan1 = new Image();
        spartan1.src = "spartan1.png";
        var spartan2 = new Image();
        spartan2.src = "spartan2.png";
        var spartan3 = new Image();
        spartan3.src = "spartan3.png";
        var spartan4 = new Image();
        spartan4.src = "spartan4.png";
        var spartan5 = new Image();
        spartan5.src = "spartan5.png";
        var stone = new Image();
        stone.src = "stone.png";

        function game() {
            update();
            render();
        }

        function player() {
            if (charFrame === 1) {
                context.drawImage(spartan1, playerx, playery);
            } else if (charFrame === 2) {
                context.drawImage(spartan2, playerx, playery);
            } else if (charFrame === 3) {
                context.drawImage(spartan3, playerx, playery);
            } else if (charFrame === 4) {
                context.drawImage(spartan4, playerx, playery);
            } else if (charFrame === 5) {
                context.drawImage(spartan5, playerx, playery);
            }
        }

        function ground() {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i += 55) {
                context.drawImage(stone, i, groundY);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i += 55) {
                context.drawImage(stone, i, groundY+55);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i += 55) {
                context.drawImage(stone, i, groundY+110);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i += 55) {
                context.drawImage(stone, i, groundY+165);
            }
        }

        function manager() {
            ground();
            while (keys[68] || keys[39]) {
                charFrame++;
                setTimeout(function() {

                }, 100);
            }   
            player();
        }

        function update() {
            manager();
            player();
        }

        function render() {
            context.fillStyle = "#AFE4FF";
            context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
            manager();
        }

        setInterval(function() {
            game();
        }, 1000/30);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I know it ***HAS*** to be the setTimeout, but I have tried to fix this problem many times. The images don't even change.

Comment: you should not use settimeout inside a loop, it won get you your desired functionality. js will run your loop untill it completes and only then it will run all functions in the settimeouts. read more of javascript stack and event loop

Comment: Why do you redraw the game after 1000/30 milliseconds? IDK I am a noob  in making web games. I think it can be one of the issues.

Comment: 30fps. 1second/30frames

Comment: Ori Price then what do I do instead?

Comment: BTW try using clearRect instead of fillRect

Comment: I put fillRect on purpose

Comment: @OriPrice ClearRect will clear a rectangle, fillRect will fill a rectangle with a certain color. Unless you want your canvas to be transparent, it's generally better to fill it with the specific background color you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `manager` function gets called 30 times per second, you should check your keypress once per frame using an if statement instead of a loop:

```
function manager() {
    ground();
    if (keys[68] || keys[39]) {
        charFrame++;
    }
}
```

In addition, your `manager` function is getting called twice per frame, once in the `update` function and once in the `render` function. Also, your `player` function is called both in `update` and in `manager`, again twice per frame. Your code will need some refactoring in order to work properly, to make sure nothing gets called twice per frame.

Comment: I updated my code a lot. That gave me an idea, thanks!